# Problem Getting the logged user ID in my Symfony local project

Tags: php, symfony

I am currently working on a edit task function and after submitting the edited task, it should redirect to a page that loads all the tasks a user made (tasks). To load the tasks page, I pass a parameter which is the user Id to load only the tasks made by the logged user.

My only problem is when I redirect to the tasks page after editing a task. I want to pass a second parameter 'ID' but I cannot get the ID of the user.[image: screenshot of editor, code and message]
When using the UserInterface $user I only get 3 possible function but in my User Entity I have the 'getId()' function.

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UsersRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: UsersRepository::class)]
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $role = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    #[Assert\Regex(
        pattern: '/\d/',
        match: false,
    )]
    private ?string $name = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    #[Assert\Regex('/[a-zA-Z ]/')]
    private ?string $surname = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    #[Assert\Email(
        message: "El email '{{ value }}' no es valido"
    )]
    private ?string $email = null;

    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $password = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?\DateTimeImmutable $created_at = null;


    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'user_id', targetEntity: Task::class)]
    private Collection $tasks;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'user_id', targetEntity: Post::class)]
    private Collection $posts;
    private array $roles = [];

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->tasks = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->posts = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->created_at = new \DateTimeImmutable();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }
```

I also tried to user the Security $security, but I still get the three functions like before.

I was actually able to retrieve the user Id using the tasksRepository, since it is a task object with a userID that contains the user that created it. But I still want to know why the UserInterface is not working for me. Or what am I messing up? Thanks[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvkl7.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about PHPStorm's auto-complete, it only knows that your getting a `UserInterface` from the method used to retrieve the `User`. You have to tell your IDE which class it will resolve to with a phpdoc block comment.

```php
use App\Entity\User;

/** @var User $user */
$user = $this->security->getUser();
```